# Get prevstate in react without es6 script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-dom

I write some script that will counting the number when we click the button in reactjs. This is my script:

```
var ComponentCounter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {count: 1};
  },
  doIncrement:function(){
    this.setState(function(prevState,currentProps){
        return {
        count:prevState.count+1
      };
    });
  },
  doDecrement:function(){
    this.setState(function(prevState,currentProps){
        return {
        count:prevState.count-1
      };
    });
  },
    render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.doIncrement}>+</Button>
            <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
            <Button onClick={this.doDecrement}>-</Button>
      </div>);  
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentCounter/>,document.getElementById('counter'));
```

But it doesn't work either when I clicked the button.

Can you fixed it and explain why?

Thanks :)

Comment: oopss i forgot that Button tag is my react component ..v .

Comment: so your problem is settled?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind context to your click handler method. Otherwise `this` inside the method will no longer point to component instance when the function is actually called. So you should do this:

```
   <Button onClick={this.doIncrement.bind(this)}>+</Button>
   <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
   <Button onClick={this.doDecrement.bind(this)}>-</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If @Bartek's answer didn't fix your problem, another area to look at is your `Button` component... are you passing the `onClick` props to an actual DOM element?

```
var Button = createClass({
   ...
   render: function() {
     return <button onClick={this.props.onChange}>{this.props.children}</button>;
     //or
     return <button {...this.props} />;
   }
});
```